# Spivak Prologue, Chapter 2, problem 7: prove $\sum_{i=1}^n k^p$ can always be written as sum of powers of n

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is problem 7 of Spivak's Calculus, 4th Edition, Prologue Chapter 2:

> Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^n k^p$$ can always be written in the form $$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + An^{p} + Bn^{p-1} + Cn^{p-2} + ...$$

There is also a hint to use the method from problem 6.

I have a few questions on some specific details about the solution in the solution book, which I reproduce in what follows:

Let A be the set of all natural numbers for which $$\sum_{i=1}^n k^p$$ can be written in the form $$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + An^{p} + Bn^{p-1} + Cn^{p-2} + ...$$.

Using induction on $p$, for $p=1$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n^2}{2} + n$$

so $p=1$ is in $A$.

Suppose the statement is true for all natural numbers smaller than $p$ (actually the solution book has smaller than or equals; **so here is the first question: is it $<$ or $\leq$ here?**).

The Binomial Theorem yields: $$(k+1)^{p+1}-k^{p+1} = (p+1)k^p + terms\ involving \sum_{k=1}^n k^r for\ r < p\tag{1}$$

By our induction assumption, we can write each $\sum_{k=1}^n k^r$ as an expression involving powers $n^s$ with $s\leq p$.

Writing out $(1)$ for $k=1,...,n$ we obtain:
$$2^{p+1}-1^{p+1}=(p+1)1^p +\ ...$$
$$3^{p+1}-2^{p+1}=(p+1)2^p +\ ...$$
$$(...)$$
$$(n+1)^{p+1}-n^{p+1}=(p+1)n^p +\ ...$$

Adding the equations, we obtain:

$$(n+1)^{p+1} - 1 = (p+1)\sum_{k=1}^n k^p +\ terms\ involving\ \sum_{k=1}^n k^r,\ for\ r<p\tag{2}$$

Now at this point, the solution actually says we obtain something else: $$\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^p+\ terms\ involving\ \sum_{k=1}^n k^r,\ for\ r<p\tag{3}$$

**So the second question is:** what assumptions are involved in obtaining $(3)$? Ie, in (2) does the term 1 on the lefthand side cancel with one of the terms on the righthand side? It is also true that each term on the righthand side has a (p+1) term, so is that term the one dividing the lefthand side?

Finally, as we noted above, because of the induction assumption for all natural numbers less than $p$, we can write each $\sum_{k=1}^n k^r$ as an expression involving powers of $n^s$ with $s\leq p$. Therefore, isolating $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p$ we get: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p = \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}+\ terms\ involving\ powers\ of\ n\ less\ than\ p+1$$.

Therefore, if $s$ is in $A$ for $s<p$ then $p$ is in $A$; therefore by induction $A=N$.

**Final question:** is this considered a rigorous proof?

Comment: It is not the best proof if you are looking for perfect rigor, because the usage of terminology like "terms involving", and the statement itself, which doesn't assert the nature of $A,B,C$ etc. , are imprecisions in themselves. In terms of conversion to a rigorous proof, it will take five minutes to make everything he says super-rigorous. Finally, to your second question, we can take the $1$ to the left and divide by $(p+1)$ without divisibility issues, because we are only demanding rational coefficients, so it's okay to have an uncancelled $p+1$ in the denominator.

Comment: So do you want a "super-rigorous" version of the above proof of Spivak? That I can write an answer about, if required.

Comment: I don't need one, but since I intend on completing this book I am always in search of new types of proofs. So the "1" divided by p+1 is simply placed on the righthand side in the "terms involving..." part? It's just not completely crystal clear where the 1 went.

Comment: Correct. So the $1$ goes to the other side, and when you divide by $p+1$ you are not worried about having integers, so  the $1$ and the division by $p+1$ go into the "terms involving" part, it still remains a "terms involving" part because you are only changing the coefficients of those sums, still keeping them rational. That's why the proof works out.

Comment: Thanks, feel free to submit a rigorous proof. I think eventually I'll be able to write one if I continue with this book, but am definitely curious to see what that looks like in this case.

Comment: On your say, I will attempt one. I actually was writing one but decided to converse with you and understand your issue prior to doing so, but now I will proceed.

Comment: Managed it. The identity looks beautiful.

Comment: No one answered your first question it seems. Is $\leq p$ a typo for $<p$? I'd be grateful if anyone could confirm.

Answer (score 4):

I think Spivak has just been a little lax, probably intentionally since it was not his point of focus. If we go a little more precisely into things, we can be far more direct : we can get $A,B,C$ etc.

---

Indeed, fix $n$ and $N$ positive integers. We have by the binomial formula:
$$
(N+1)^{n+1} = \binom{n+1}{0}N^0 + \binom{n+1}{1} N^{1} + \ldots + \binom{n+1}{n}_{(=n+1)} N^{n} + \binom{n+1}{n+1}_{(=1)} N^{n+1} \\ \implies (N+1)^{n+1} - N^{n+1} = \binom{n+1}{0}N^0 + \binom{n+1}{1} N^{1} + \ldots +(n+1) N^{n} \\ \implies \frac{(N+1)^{n+1} -N^{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{\binom{n+1}{0}}{n+1}N^0 + \frac{\binom{n+1}{1}}{n+1} N^1 + ... + N^n \\ 
\implies N^n = \frac{(N+1)^{n+1} -N^{n+1}}{n+1} -\frac{\binom{n+1}{0}}{n+1}N^0 - \frac{\binom{n+1}{1}}{n+1} N^1 - \cdots - \frac{\binom{n+1}{n-1}}{n+1} N^{n-1}
$$

and now when we sum from $N=0$ to $K$, the first term on the right has telescoping cancellations and the rest sum up . The following emerges :
$$
\sum_{N=0}^K N^n = \frac{(K+1)^{n+1}}{n+1} - \frac 1{n+1} - \frac{\binom{n+1}{0}}{n+1}\sum_{N=0}^K N^0 - \frac{\binom{n+1}{1}}{n+1} \sum_{n=0}^K N^1 - \cdots - \frac{\binom{n+1}{n-1}}{n+1} \sum_{n=0}^K N^{n-1}
$$

which provides the *exact* relation between the sums in question, the super-rigorous and exact proof. This can be used to calculate the first few sum formulas as well, and also provides intuition for why the Bernoulli numbers come into the general formula, from their recurrence relation. You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for more details.

---

Of course, note that Spivak did not want to mention all this because he felt that writing out the details was not his intention there, he just wanted to use induction. If you want a proof that does just that, without giving you an explicit formula, then your formulation will be slightly different , and you will have the following :

> For each $n = 1,2,...$ there exist rational numbers $C_{n,0},C_{n,1},...,C_{n,n}$ such that for every $K=1,2,...$ , we have :
> $$
> \sum_{N=0}^K N^n = \frac{(N+1)^{n+1}}{n+1} + C_{n,n}N^n + ... + C_{n,0}
> $$

and how to prove this? Now go by induction, and $n=1$ is clear, and for induction, assume truth for $1,...,n-1$ and you want to prove the statement for $n$. All you need to do is repeat the above argument , but replace each exact quantity (like the binomial coefficients) except $\binom{n+1}{n}$ and $\binom{n+1}{n+1}$ by saying there exist rational numbers in those places. So for example, you would use binomial theorem to say : there exist rational numbers $r_0,...,r_{n-1}$ such that :
$$
(N+1)^{n+1} = r_0N^0 + r_1 N^{1} + \ldots + (n+1)N^{n} +  N^{n+1}
$$   Then you just have to do the summation, perform the manipulations exactly as done before, and you will land up with the same sum, except with $r_i$ instead of the binomial coefficients, which does it. (super-rigorously, if you like!)

Answer (score 0):

Let $s_p(n)=1^p+2^p+\cdots+ n^p$. We know that $s_1(n) = {1 \over 2} n^2+ q_1(n)$, where $q_1$ is a polynomial with degree $\partial q_1 \le 1$. So suppose we know that $s_r(n) = {1 \over r+1}n^{r+1}+ q_r(n)$, with $\partial q_r \le r$ for $r=1,...,p-1$.

Then
$(k+1)^{p+1} - k^{p+1} = \sum_{i=0}^{p} \binom{p+1}{i} k^i = (p+1)k^p +  \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \binom{p+1}{i} k^i $.
Rearranging gives
$k^p = {1 \over p+1}((k+1)^{p+1} - k^{p+1} - \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \binom{p+1}{i} k^i )$.

Summing both sides with $\sum_{k=1}^n$ gives
$s_{p}(n) = {1 \over p+1}((n+1)^{p+1} - 1 - \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \binom{p+1}{i} s_i(n) )$ and since
$\partial \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} \binom{p+1}{i} s_i \le p-1$, we have the desired result.